# share a struct with lifetime parameter which implements `dyn` trait across threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

How to share a struct with lifetime parameter which implements `dyn` trait across threads safely. This is my code

main.rs

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, mpsc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Button {
    
}

impl Draw for Button {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("draw button");
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct SelectionBox {
    
}

impl Draw for SelectionBox {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("draw selection box");
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct TextField {
    
}

impl Draw for TextField {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("draw text field");
    }
}


pub struct RunningThreadInterface<T> {
    pub instance: Arc<T>,
    pub thread_join_handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

pub trait StartThread<T> {
    fn start(self, thread_id: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<T>;
    fn run(&self);
}

pub trait TerminateThread {
    fn stop(&mut self);
    fn wait(self);
}

struct Screen<'a> {
    widgets: Mutex<Vec<&'a (dyn Draw + Send + Sync)>>,
    rx: Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<String>>,
    terminate_flag: AtomicBool,
}

impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    fn new(rx: mpsc::Receiver<String>) -> Screen<'a> {
        Screen {
            widgets: Mutex::new(Vec::new()),
            rx: Mutex::new(rx),
            terminate_flag: AtomicBool::new(false),
        }
    }
    
    fn add(&mut self, widget: &'a (dyn Draw + Send + Sync)) {
        self.widgets.lock().unwrap().push(widget);
    }
    
    fn draw_widgets(&self) {
        for widget in &*self.widgets.lock().unwrap() {
            widget.draw();
        }
    }
}


impl<'a> StartThread<Screen<'a>> for Screen<'a> {
    fn start(self, thread_id: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<Screen<'a>> {
        let screen = Arc::new(self);
        RunningThreadInterface {
            instance: Arc::clone(&screen),
            thread_join_handle: thread::Builder::new().name(thread_id).spawn(move || screen.run()).ok().unwrap(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&self) {
        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            self.rx.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> TerminateThread for RunningThreadInterface<Screen<'a>> {
    fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.instance.terminate_flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }

    fn wait(self) {
        self.thread_join_handle.join();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let button: Button = Default::default();
    let selection_box: SelectionBox = Default::default();
    let text_field: TextField = Default::default();
    
    let (_tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    
    let mut screen = Screen::new(rx);
    screen.add(&button);
    screen.add(&selection_box);
    screen.add(&text_field);
    
    screen.draw_widgets();
    
    println!("");
    
    button.draw();
    selection_box.draw();
    text_field.draw();
}
```

Error

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src/main.rs:90:33
   |
85 | impl<'a> StartThread<Screen<'a>> for Screen<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
86 |     fn start(self, thread_id: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<Screen<'a>> {
   |              ---- `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
...
90 |             thread_join_handle: thread::Builder::new().name(thread_id).spawn(move || screen.run()).ok().unwrap(),
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                 |
   |                                 `self` escapes the method body here
   |                                 argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `Screen<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
   = note: the struct `Screen<'a>` is invariant over the parameter `'a`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
```

Please note I cannot change the existing syntax of `StartThread` and `TerminateThread` traits, but I'm open for suggestions if the exiting design isn't good(can be made better)

Comment: You want to look into thread scope

Comment: @JakubDóka can you elaborate the issue that I'm facing...I thought `Arc` instance inside `start` method owns `self`(`Screen` struct object in this case)

Comment: If you want an object to hold a reference to another object shared between threads, it needs to hold an `Arc<Mutex<...>` I believe

Comment: Nitpick: Wrapping MPSC receiver in `Mutex` is an antipattern; use MPMC instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this generic enough for you, but if you restrict the generic lifetime to be static (`impl<'a: 'static> StartThread<Screen<'a>> for Screen<'a>`) then your example runs.

You can also do it in this equivalent way:

```rust
impl StartThread<Screen<'static>> for Screen<'static> {
    fn start(self, thread_id: String) -> RunningThreadInterface<Screen<'static>> {
        let screen = Arc::new(self);
        RunningThreadInterface {
            instance: Arc::clone(&screen),
            thread_join_handle: thread::Builder::new().name(thread_id).spawn(move || screen.run()).ok().unwrap(),
        }
    }

    fn run(&self) {
        while !self.terminate_flag.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
            self.rx.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a lifetime and constraining it to be `'static`? This is foolish. Why don't use `'static` in the first place?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It is a little silly sure, but it reduces the changes needed to make the original code work and it is useful to show that lifetimes can be used to restrict each other.